# How to show up feed along with promoted posts?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I was trying to make an Instagram-like app with Flutter. I which users can promote their for some amount, and once the promotion is done I'll add the post id into the promoted posts database.

Now, I want to focus on natural posts (I mean posts of user's 'following list') so I used a StreamBuilder to listen to the friends' collection.

Meanwhile, I also wanted to mix the content with promoted posts. Seriously, can't find a solution.

Any idea about implementing this? This will be a great help for me.

The promoted posts' collection would be of a large space, so I'm kinda worried about retrieving all documents in the collection at once and showing it up.

Let me know your thoughts :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear of your question but still what I can say is,

If you want to mix both of the posts, then just add data from both stream builders to a list. Its like list.addAll(data)

Another thing is, you are worried about large data load. You can load/fetch data on scroll. You can find tutorials by searching lazy loading, infinite scrolling etc.

Let me know if you got it!

Comment: Thanks, lazy loading seems a good idea. I wanted to know how can I listen to two different collections at the same time. Is this possible?

Comment: @SreelalTS, rxdart package has some handy tools for merging multiple streams. You can look into that (`Observable.merge`).

Comment: as @HasilT said,
using rx dart you can do it. rx dart gives more controls to the stream/sink. So you can insert your data after fetching by sink and get it using stream. Rx dart gives you different types of capabilities to these streams. 

I suggest you to try this tutorial of bloc pattern. You will get it.

https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1

please do not forget to vote the answer.